# Read giant int-Array from binary file

Tags: c#, performance, casting, binary

## Task

I have a huge file (≈ 20 GB) containing integers and want to read them in C#.

## Simple approach

Reading the file to memory (into a byte-array) is quite fast (using an SSD, the whole file fits into memory). But when I read these bytes with a binary-reader (via memory-stream) and the ReadInt32-method takes significantly longer than reading the file to memory. I expected to be disk-IO the bottleneck, but it's the conversion!

## Idea and question

Is there a way to directly cast the whole byte-array into an int-array not having to convert it one-by-one with the ReadInt32-method?

```
class Program
{
    static int size = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
    static string filename = @"E:\testfile";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Write(filename, size);
        int[] result = Read(filename, size);
        Console.WriteLine(result.Length);
    }

    static void Write(string filename, int size)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create), Encoding.UTF8);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            bw.Write(i);
        }
        bw.Close();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("File written in {0}ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
    }

    static int[] Read(string filename, int size)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(buffer), Encoding.UTF8);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("File read into memory in {0}ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Start();

        int[] result = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            result[i] = br.ReadInt32();
        }
        br.Close();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Byte-array casted to int-array in {0}ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));

        return result;
    }
}
```

- File written in 5499ms
- File read into memory in 455ms
- Byte-array casted to int-array in 3382ms

Comment: You'll have to perform the conversion eventually.  Can you just read the array into memory and use BitConverter to get the values from the array as needed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206391/directly-reading-large-binary-file-in-c-sharp-w-out-copying.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Seems he already knows how to read the file into memory.

Comment: Golly 20GB might be a lot to read in one go.  Do you need all of it in one sitting. Otherwise my first thought would have been memory-mapped files but then that's unmanaged code by default.

Comment: People are a bit confused.  Why don't you show us the code you have so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could allocate a temporary `byte[]` buffer with convenient size and use the `Buffer.BlockCopy` method to copy bytes to the `int[]` array incrementally.

```
BinaryReader reader = ...;
int[] hugeIntArray = ...;

const int TempBufferSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
byte[] tempBuffer = reader.ReadBytes(TempBufferSize);
Buffer.BlockCopy(tempBuffer, 0, hugeIntArray, offset, TempBufferSize);
```

Where `offset` is a current (for the current iteration) starting index in the destination `hugeIntArray` array.

Comment: ReadBytes is likely to suffer the same fate, though I'm not certain of that.

Comment: I read the whole file into memory at first with ReadAllBytes.

Comment: This is significantly faster: File read into memory in 439ms,
Byte-array casted to int-array in 105ms